# После установки Yii2 ошибка в mkdir()

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vagrant

Установил Yii2 по [этой](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-start-installation.html) инструкции, composer тоже ставил так, как указано в ней-же. Apache2 настроил так, чтобы он указывал на дирректорию */var/www/yii/basic/web*, попробовал запустить - ошибка. Пишет мне:

```
Exception – yii\base\Exception
Failed to create directory "/var/www/yii/basic/runtime/logs": mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Создал вручную. После этого стал ругаться так:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException

The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/yii/basic/web/assets
```

Почему дирректория недоступна для записи, я понять так и не смог. Пробовал разное - начиная от **chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www** и вплоть до совсем уж **chmod -R 777 /var/www/yii**, но ничего не изменилось. Apache перезапускал неоднократно, машину перезапускал, не помогает. Как поправить? Срочно, кровь из носу, нужен рабочий Yii2.

Система работает под Vagrant, бокс ubuntu/xenial64 из числа стандартных с оффсайта.

P.S. Ещё пять копеек:

```
ubuntu@yiisrv:~$ ps auxwwww | grep apache
root      1838  0.0  3.7 451528 38444 ?        Ss   19:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1839  0.0  1.8 452068 18884 ?        S    19:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1840  0.0  1.9 452068 19760 ?        S    19:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1841  0.0  1.0 451552 10756 ?        S    19:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1842  0.0  1.0 451552 10756 ?        S    19:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1843  0.0  1.0 451552 10756 ?        S    19:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1851  0.0  1.0 451552 10756 ?        S    20:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Получается что, Apache работает от www-data как и должен, но какой-то один поток запущен от рута? Может, и в этом дело.

Вывод **ls -la /var/www/yii/basic**:

```
ubuntu@yiisrv:/var/www/yii/basic/web/assets$ ls -la /var/www/yii/basic
total 208
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Mar 22 19:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Mar 22 19:47 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     37 Feb  1 16:55 .bowerrc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    408 Feb  1 16:55 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1622 Feb  1 16:55 LICENSE.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5829 Feb  1 16:55 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Mar 22 19:47 apache_logs
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 assets
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    806 Feb  1 16:55 codeception.yml
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 commands
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1740 Feb  1 16:55 composer.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 106613 Mar 22 19:30 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 config
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 controllers
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 mail
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 models
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5141 Feb  1 16:55 requirements.php
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Mar 22 20:05 runtime
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 tests
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Mar 22 19:30 vendor
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 views
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Feb  1 16:55 web
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    556 Feb  1 16:55 yii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    515 Feb  1 16:55 yii.bat
```

Сам Yii крашится вот на этой строчке:

```
} elseif (!is_writable($this->basePath)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The directory is not writable by the Web process: {$this->basePath}");
```

Comment: сама директория `/var/www/yii/basic/web/assets` существует? Там скорее всего банальная проверка на то, можно ли писать по такому-то пути, и ОС говорит что нельзя, потому что директории не существует.

Comment: Да, существует. В ней даже лежит .gitignore

Comment: а прикрепите к ответу вывод `ls -la /var/www/yii/basic`

Comment: добавил в тело вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как можно увидеть из вывода, пользователь и группа у файлов и директорий в `/var/www/yii/basic` не изменилась (`ubuntu/ubuntu`). Это потому что вы монтируете файлы проекта в VM с помощью Vagrant, а не копируете их непосредственно в VM. В этом случае вам надо добавить пользователя `www-data` в группу `ubuntu`

```
sudo usermod -a -G ubuntu www-data
```

И перезапустить Apache. Write-права для группы на `assets` уже есть, поэтому должно всё заработать.

Comment: ubuntu@yiisrv:/var/www/yii/basic/web/assets$ sudo usermod -a -G vagrant www-data
usermod: group 'vagrant' does not exist

Comment: Ну тогда `sudo chmod o+w /var/www/yii/basic/assets`

Comment: лучше изменить owner/group у точки монтирования в vagrantfile, думаю

Comment: Или изменить пользователя, из под которого запускается apache2

Comment: Подождите :) Zhukov Roman, usermod делать на хостовой системе? не в вагранте?

Comment: usermod делать естественно в вагранте. Сейчас проверил команду, всё ОК у меня

Comment: @КапитанФлинт на стороне хоста точно ничего делать не надо (вам же еще работать с этими файлами)

Comment: Zhukov Roman, команду пробовал выполнить в вагранте. Не сработало, вывод писал выше

Comment: @КапитанФлинт поправил ответ :) Уже сплю, надо не в группу vagrant, а в группу ubuntu

Comment: @ZhukovRoman спасибо :) всё получилось. Вроде уже давно с никсами дело имею, и с апачем, и с вагрантом, но вот такие мелочи пока ещё проскакивают :)) благодарю, в общем :)

Comment: @КапитанФлинт you are welcome! У вас тоже хороший и развёрнутый вопрос, побольше бы таких :)